# Django multilingual with pages in one language disabling switch

Tags: django, translation, mezzanine

I am developing a website using Django Mezzanine.

I have some pages using a model derived from Mezzanine Page model with translatable fields (using i18n) and this works.

However I have some pages relative to some events in given countries, so they are only in one language, and they use a model derived from Mezzanine Displayable model, without translatable fields but a language attribute.

In the list I tried to put links including the language of the page (like /en/events/event/eventslug ).
I tried to add `translation.activate(lang_code)` to the view.

This way I get the page in the wanted language (I use `{% trans %}` template tags).

The problem comes when I visit the page from another language (for example if I am on the filter page in Spanish and go to an English event). Then the language switch (mezzanine form sending a POST request to /i18n/) doesn't work any more (I am locked in English)
The switch still work in private navigation for example as long as I don't visit one of this pages from another language.

How can I fix this?
I am out of ideas as of why...

Update: I changed the urlpattern so it is not i18n anymore (I think it makes more sense) but as I still need `translation.activate(lang_code)` for the `{% trans %}` tags my problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the fact that if you use `translation.activate(language)` then you need to use `translation.deactivate()`.
So that would have required the use of a middleware to make it work properly.

However I found the [i18next module](http://pythonhosted.org/django-i18next/) allowing to override the locale in the template, so I defined the context 'lang_code' in my view and used `{% overridelocale lang_code %}` in my template.